# How can I stop a particular app from opening a webpage in Safari by itself?

Tags: macos, mac, safari

The Bitwarden application opens a webpage in Safari that thanks me for downloading the app. It does this when I run the terminal command `sudo touch /Applications/*`. I need to run this for a particular script. Is there a way to block the app from automatically opening Safari completely?

Comment: Why on earth do you want to touch every file in Applications?  But really you should complain to the makes of Bitwarden.

Comment: As you touch the directory containing the app, the app may think that you just downloaded the app (time if dir more recent than time of exe which has time of creation which is when the app was put on AppStore). But the question of @benwiggy is very important : why do you do that ??